# Query not working. page not found in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

This is my show.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>


        <h1>{{ $task->body }}</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is the route

```
Route::get('/tasks/{$task}', function ($id) {

    $task = DB::table('tasks')->find($id);


    return view('tasks.show', compact('task'));
});
```

The problem is that it shows this 'Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.' instead of the result.

Comment: What is the url You're opening in browser? also fix Your route: `/tasks/{$task}'` to `/tasks/{task}'`  read the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-parameters

Comment: this is the url http://127.0.0.1:8000/tasks/1

Comment: and what to fix in url

Comment: also fix Your route: `'/tasks/{$task}'` to `'/tasks/{task}'`   remove dollar sign in routing

Comment: thanks buddy it worked

Comment: One way to make sure your routes are properly set is to use `artisan route`.  What do you get when you run `php artisan route:list --path=tasks` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres a couple of things wrong with your code:

The route `/tasks/{$task}` is not defined correctly. use `/task/{task}`. Read the documentation on [Laravel routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing) to learn how to create routes in Laravel

I'm pretty sure wildcards in routes should have the same name as the parameter in the function you are binding the route to. (And even if they don't have to, it's generally a good idea, to keep the 2 consistent.)

So you should either use `/tasks/{task}` and `function ($task)` or `/tasks/{id}` and `function ($id)`

Again, read the documentation on [Laravel routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing).

Comment: @MohanSharma Can you update the question with the code you currently have? Have you read the article I linked?